# javascript redirect page and refresh cache at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem when i redirect an user after edit profile and he edits the profile pic. I redirect him to his user page but it doesnt display the edited pic only if he manualy refresh page. Here is my code of the profile_edit.php page that redirects to profil.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = $(\'form\');

    var b = $(\'#submit1\'); // upload button


    b.click(function(){
        // implement with ajaxForm Plugin
        f.ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(e){
                window.location=\'profil.php?user='.$user_session.'\';
            },
            error: function(e){

            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Please show the code for loading new image

Answer (score 1):

add one more parameter with your url for cache busting some thing like this

```
window.location=\'profil.php?pram='+Math.random()+'&user='.$user_session.'\';
```

Comment: tryed this, but i still need to refresh the page to see the new pic

Comment: do you see new parameter in your url, which you have added?

Comment: yep i see it `profil.php?pram=0.8248080820349878&user=3`

Comment: it didnt work, i solved it with changing name in database for each update, before i was renaming pics as user id and i changed that

Answer (score 0):

At first - you can add some hash, to prefer caching like

```
window.location=\'profil.php?user='.$user_session.'&rand='.mt_rand().'\';
```

This will create new url - so browser will load page as new

And it is possible, that you need add this trick to image url -- please check this moment

if you need to refresh page ( your current url equal to new one ) - use

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

at success callback instead redirect - true say to browser to refresh page